# Measuring high currents with toroids

Tags: current, sensor, current-sensing, current-sensor

I got a PT27312 current sensor ([datasheet](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/901/PT27312-pdf.php)), I wonder if I can use it to measure currents up to 100A AC/DC.

I couldn't find any specifications in respect of the current measurement range.
I only know I have to calculate a burden resistor for it.

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: You won't be able to measure DC.

Comment: No, you can not measure DC currents with it without building en effective LEM module. It specifies 50-200 kHz, so 50/60 Hz is out of the question too due to saturation or severe derating.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both of you. Can I place it to sense the switcing currents around a Mosfet or a an Igbt then, to control the range?

Comment: It can sense AC currents that pass through the hole. That is what it can do. It appears to me that the intended use is in AC to DC switch mode converters. The line-voltage wire would be fed through the hole in the sensor. This would allow sensing current at line voltage while maintaining isolation. If you are not building an AC to DC switch mode converter there may be better options for you.

Comment: Thans a lot mkeith, yes I've got a few of these and some LEMS HM05 but these have limited range, I salvaged the PT27312 from some SMPS, Power Factor correction boards??? I need to make some powerful 50Amps variable SMPS supply for induction heating and a DIY SMPS welder, so I need some help in finding easy and relible ways to monitor and measure high currents.

Comment: ACS has some products that will work. Hall effect based. Some of them have isolation ratings that would probably be adequate for your application. One example is the ACS712. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

While the inductive PT27312 seems like a good idea, you may look at a simpler solution. A current shunt is simply a very low value resistor. With a simple amplifier or a panel meter you can actively control the current via your SMPS or just monitor it via the panel meter.

Search for "current shunt 100 amps" and you will find several very low priced options. A word of caution though, some of the low cost panel meters are easily destroyed by hooking up the current shunt to the high side instead of low side of the circuit.

If you want, you can make your own current shunt, however, calibrating it will require some higher precision equipment than a simple multi meter.

Comment: Thanks a lot Noahreyburn, I used resistors in high side sensing in a lot of linear power supplies, but I can't get all I need where I live especially presicision high Watt resistors, etc! I have to tinker a bit, besides, I mostly need this for AC swift shutdown before valuable transistors are blown up. That's why I also want to learn new ways of controlling high current.

Comment: @Electroprime70 Sure, no problem. I completely understand the drive to learn new techniques. I found this very interesting reference guide regarding current sensing using hall effect sensors. Take a look: [link](https://www.melexis.com/en/documents/documentation/application-notes/application-note-current-sensor-design-guide)

Comment: Thanks a lot I considered the link and the info, I just got busy doing something else. I had some success in current trafos and their signal conditioning.